# applying correlation to all columns in R

Tags: r, correlation

I am trying to apply a single function to find the correlation between all numeric columns and the target variable (separately, one by one)

This is the code I was able to determine a single column's correlation. I'm trying to limit my correlations above 0.4:

```
> if(abs(cor(train$YearBuilt, train$SalePrice)) > .4) {
+       print(abs(cor(train$YearBuilt, train$SalePrice)))
+     }
[1] 0.5228973
```

I would like to be able to print the column name followed by the correlation, and then the next column name and its correlation, etc.

Comment: Please provide a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).

Comment: why not using `cor(train)` which gives you the correlation matrix? And then you can filter for values greater than 0.4. Writing your own function does not make any sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility using dplyr. A little indulgent with the pipe, but it does your filtering by 0.4 and retains the variable names too.

```
> train = select(iris, -Species)
> head(train)
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width
1          5.1         3.5          1.4         0.2
2          4.9         3.0          1.4         0.2
3          4.7         3.2          1.3         0.2
4          4.6         3.1          1.5         0.2
5          5.0         3.6          1.4         0.2
6          5.4         3.9          1.7         0.4
> train %>% 
+   summarize_all(funs(cor(., iris$Sepal.Length))) %>% 
+   t() %>% 
+   as.data.frame() %>% 
+   rownames_to_column("var") %>% 
+   rename(cors = V1) %>% 
+   filter(cors > 0.4)
           var      cors
1 Sepal.Length 1.0000000
2 Petal.Length 0.8717538
3  Petal.Width 0.8179411
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of finding the correlation of iris$Petal.Length with the other numerical variables:

```
vars <- c("Sepal.Length", "Sepal.Width", "Petal.Width")
all <- lapply(vars, function(i) list(x= iris[,i], y=iris[,"Petal.Length"]))
lapply(all, function(x) do.call(cor, x))

[[1]]
[1] 0.8717538

[[2]]
[1] -0.4284401

[[3]]
[1] 0.9628654
```

Comment: This is not what the OP wants.